# AutoCompleteTextView threshhold is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-adapter

I want to show dropdown list even for completely empty string. Because my coded logic in `Adapter` is that if filtering constraint is empty or null, show all results available. But for some reason, results are filtered and returned, but dropdown is hidden while text is empty.

I set threshold to 0 but its not working. I even tried negative values.
I tried to override `afterTextChanged` listener and force to show dropdown while query is empty or null, but `AutoCompleteTextview` is forcing to hide dropdown anyways.

In documentation I found this line:

```
When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.
```

That means I cant do this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own custom autocomplete text view by extending e.g. the `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

Here is mine:

```
public class InstantAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    public InstantAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InstantAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InstantAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused && getAdapter() != null) {
            performFiltering(getText(), 0);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP != event.getAction()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        if (!isPopupShowing() && getAdapter() != null) {
            showDropDown();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in the layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        
    <your.package.name.util.InstantAutoCompleteTextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/hint"
         android:imeOptions="actionDone"
         android:inputType="text|textCapWords" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Wow, there is no other option? Showing drop down list even when user didn't typed anything yet seems like normal case, I don't understand why 0 threshold is changed to 1 by native code, lol.